# Eclipse Plugin Fragment

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

Does anyone have a "hello world" sample or tutorial for creating an Eclipse plugin fragment?

I have a working host plugin that, for the sake of simplicity, is just this...

```
public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Hello....");
    super.start(context);
    plugin = this;
}

public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Goodbye...");
    plugin = null;
    super.stop(context);
}
```

Simple enough and works. Now I want to add a fragment to that host, which seems not as simple as creating a plugin host. I just don't see how to create a fragment project and add logic to it.  Let's say I just want to do something simple and have the fragment to print a "Hello2" at `start()` and "Goodbye2" at `stop()`. Can someone give me a working example?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. *Eclipse* -> *File* -> *New...* -> *Fragment project* -> set the host plugin (which is either in your workspace or in plugins in target platform).
2. Open *Plugin manifest editor* (you can do it by clicking on `build.properties`, `manifest.mf` or `fragment.xml` - if there is no such a file, create it by hand)
3. In tab *Extentions* click *Add..* and add `org.eclipse.ui.startup` and browse class which implements `org.eclipse.ui.IStartup` class.
4. Create this class and implement it. You need to implement method `earlyStartup()` which is entry point to the fragment.

*Note: The lines below are just example. I didn't test it so there might be errors...*

All you need is this (this is project structure / directory structure):

- **Fragment-Project** - root dir

  - /**META-INF**

    - **MANIFEST.MF**
  - /**src** (which is source directory)

    - **FragmentStartClass.java** (which implement org.eclipse.ui.IStartup interface and earlyStartup method)
  - **build.properties**
  - **fragment.xml**

**META-INF/MANIFEST.MF** content:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2 
Bundle-Name: FragmentProject 
Bundle-SymbolicName: FragmentProject;singleton:=true 
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0 
Bundle-ClassPath: src/,. 
Fragment-Host: *HostPluginProjectSymbolicName*;bundle-version="1.0.0" 
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.5 
Require-Bundle:
```

**build.properties** content:

```
source.. = src,\
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,
              .,
                  fragment.xml
```

**fragment.xml** content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.2"?>
<fragment>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.startup">
      <startup
            class="FragmentStartClass">
      </startup>
   </extension>
</fragment>
```

**FragmentStartClass.java** content:

```
import org.eclipse.ui.IStartup;


public class FragmentStartClass implements IStartup {

    public void earlyStartup() {
       System.out.println("Hello World From Fragment!");

    }


}
```

Comment: @Nathan thanks for information. Unfortunately it's been a long time since I worked with Eclipse and I even don't know for which version this solution works. I guess it's Eclipse Galileo (https://projects.eclipse.org/releases/galileo).  Could you post a working solution, if you know it, please? Thanks...

Answer (score 4):

Well, first off what are you trying to accomplish?  Are you sure fragments are the solution?

Fragments are simply additions to an existing plugin.  There is no Bundle-Activator to "startup" the fragment.  You just gain the additional resources in the fragment.  You could use an extension point to inform the host that some particular functionality was extended by a present fragment.  Think of it as merging the two at runtime.

See [this note](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_a_plug-in_fragment%3F) from the [Eclipse Wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do this without the host plugin knowing something about loading the fragment's extra implementation code.

For example:

```
MyInterface o = null;
try {
    Class<?> c = getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("my.fragment.Activator");
    o = (MyInterface) c.newInstance();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
}

if (o != null) {
    o.start();
}
```

where MyInterface is an interface defined in the host plugin, and implemented by your fragment.

Another way might be to have the fragment provide an extension point identifying the extended class, but that is probably more than is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is better served by using [extension points](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t97608.rhtml) and separate plugins, as you want to add functionality to the base plugin.

Fragments are only used to add resources or extra classes to the base plugin.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I just created an Eclipse Fragment that contains some PMD Java Rule classes.

Next to the class files, there is **only one file** required in that Jar: `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: com.acme.tools.pmd
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.acme.tools.pmd;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Fragment-Host: net.sourceforge.pmd.eclipse.plugin;bundle-version="3.2.6"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.5
```

I tried this with current Eclipse 3.7. Deployment is by placing the Jar file into `<eclipse root>/dropins/plugins` (create that folder if it's not yet there).

Comment: I am also trying to deploy Fragment project with Update Site & Jar File.For update-site i have created Update Site for Fragment project only,But when i install in eclipse its not reflecting my changes.I have tried the method which you have mentioned above,but still i am not getting.Do i need to follow any other approach.Please help