# How do I resolve a dependency in an Eclipse plug-in I didn't write?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to use a relatively new Eclipse plug-in (http://uqbar-tomcat-xt.sourceforge.net/download.html). It doesn't have an update site, so I can't install it through the UI in Eclipse, which usually resolves dependencies. All that's available for download is a single .jar, and the instructions on the website say to just drop it in eclipse/plugins. When I do that, it seems to work, in the sense that I get the new options in Window -> Show View that the plug-in should add. However, when I try to use either of those views, I get the following error:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.uqbar.eclipse.tomcat.xt (304).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:211)
...snip...
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator org.uqbar.eclipse.tomcat.xt.UqbarSydeoXtActivator for bundle org.uqbar.eclipse.tomcat.xt is invalid
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:157)
...snip...
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The import com.thoughtworks cannot be resolved
    XStream cannot be resolved to a type
    XStream cannot be resolved to a type
    XStream cannot be resolved to a type
```

The dependencies page of the above site lists several dependencies, including XStream. I tried downloading those .jars separately and dropping them into the eclipse/plugins directory as well, but that didn't resolve the error. When I look at the manifest in the jar, I see:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: .,commons-logging-1.0.4.jar,xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar,xstr
 eam-1.3.jar,xstream-benchmark-1.3.jar
```

But obviously the xstream jars aren't available on the classpath (which is where?). I'm not sure where I can put them so that they're recognized by the plug-in.

I've tried contacting the developers and got no response, so I'm turning to SO. Is there anything I can do, or is the plug-in packaged incorrectly?

Update: Apparently the error is in the Activator, not the plugin itself. I tried importing the plugin as a source project, but the src/ directory is empty. The plugin doesn't appear in the list of available deployable plugins when I try to export it. So this is still unsolved.

Comment: The recommended method of manually adding a plug-in from Eclipse 3.4 onwards is to drop it into the dropins directory inside Eclipse.  You might find adding plug-ins to the eclipse/plugins has no effect (this is because p2 is responsible for the eclipse/plugins directory).

Comment: Actually, putting it in the dropins directory didn't work, because it's an extension to a plug-in I've already installed (through the Eclipse UI), which is in the plugins directory. But for most other cases, yes - dropins is the way to go.

I've become sidetracked on something else (so it goes) so I haven't tried Rich's solution yet, but will report back when I do!

Answer (score 2):

You can define an Eclipse fragment with the missing dependency on its classpath (normally in the lib directory of the fragment and specified on the classpath in the manifest).

A fragment is a special type of plugin that is attached to a target plugin. The fragment is merged with the target plugin at runtime, so the classes in the plugin will have access to the jar.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673908/eclipse-plugin-fragment) for some pointers on creating a fragment.

Comment: Hm, I tried this but I'm still getting the same error. It seems to be a compile-time problem, and since fragments get logically merged at run-time it didn't solve the issue. Would I need to get the plugin source and recompile myself? Is there anything I can do to fix this, given that the source isn't available? Still waiting to hear from the developers who made it.

Answer (score 1):

Rich Seller's fix will work, though the real problem is a crappy plug-in which specifies a bunch of 3rd-party libraries on the `Bundle-ClassPath`, but doesn't actually include them!  The `Bundle-ClassPath` is the classpath internal to the bundle, so any referenced libraries should be inside the bundle.

Since the source code is included, you could re-build the plug-in with the missing dependencies (license allowing), though I think all of those third-party dependencies should be external - but that's an entirely different discussion about how to write OSGi bundles/Eclipse plug-ins.

Comment: Unfortunately the source code isn't included. All they've released is a .jar.